# InstallShield AskYesNo Dialog box is appearing behind everything

Tags: installation, installshield

So I have the following code and anytime it is called it appears behind everything else.  Does anybody have any idea of how I can make sure this prompt shows up at the front every time?

```
sPromptA = "Question that is asked to user";

MODE = NORMALMODE;

if (NO = AskYesNo(sPromptA, NO)) then
    MODE = SILENTMODE;
```

Comment: Which Windows version are you using? I see this a problem with 8.1, not with 8.0 or Win7 though...maybe I'm wrong though

Comment: It actually happens on most versions of Windows.  Vista, 7, XP but I don't think I tried it on 8.

Answer (score 2):

You can work around this:

```
HWND hRecord;
sMsg = "my message";

hRecord = MsiCreateRecord(1);
MsiRecordSetString( hRecord, 0, sMsg);
nYesNoResult = MsiProcessMessage(hMSI, INSTALLMESSAGE_USER + MB_YESNO, hRecord);
MsiCloseHandle(hRecord);

if (nYesNoResult = 6) then //6=yes 7=no
  //do something
endif;
```